# Implementing FC layers as Conv layers

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I understand that implementing Fully Connected Layer as Convolution Layer reduces parameter, but does it increases Computational Speed. If Yes, then why do people still use Fully Connected Layers?

Comment: Welcome to SO! The focus of this site is specific programming / implementation questions (see [What can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)), broad conceptual questions like yours are often closed (and may be better off at other sites like ai.SE, datascience.SE, or stats.SE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convolutional layers are used for ***low-level reasoning*** like feature extraction. At this level, using a fully connected layer would be wasteful of resources, because so many more parameters have to be computed. If you have an image of size 32x32x3, a fully connected layer would require computation of **32*32*3 = 3072** weights for the first layer. These many parameters are not required for low-level reasoning.  Features tend to have spatial locality in images, and local connectivity is sufficient for feature extraction. If you used convolutional layer, 12 filters of size 3x3, you only need to calculate **12*3*3 = 108** weights.

Fully connected layers are used for ***high-level reasoning***. These are the layers in the network which determine the final output of the convolutional network. As the reasoning becomes more complex, local connectivity is no longer sufficient, which is why fully connected layers are used in later stages of the network.

Please read [this](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) for a more detailed and visual explanation